# Is cooking with palm oil healthy?

Tags: health, vegetable-oil

Cooking oil is very important to get a good taste.
Is cooking with palm oil healthy?

Answer (score 5):

Using palm oil for cooking is fine from a health perspective, but **not** from a sustainability perspective. Often rain forests are cleared to create new palm oil plantations, so palm oil is responsible for deforestation, forest fires and loss of habitat for animals. Even [certified organic palm oil and palm oil with RSPO certification are not without these problems](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5727/99).

Other cooking oils like coconut oil or olive oil are a better choice, both from a health point of view (see [this blog](http://www.onegreenplanet.org/vegan-food/is-palm-oil-good-for-your-health/) and [this blog](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/healthy-cooking-oils#section2)) as well as from a sustainability point of view (see [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1248/99)).

Comment: The onegreenplanet.org reference for health information about palm oil seems questionable.  It doesn't cite any primary sources, only advocacy groups and soft news coverage.  It also doesn't even unambiguous come down on the side of "fine for health" - see the comment about low-grade inflammation.  Given that the question is about *health* (perhaps making it off-topic) this doesn't seem like a great citation for an answer.  But maybe the whole thing should just be migrated elsewhere.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I agree it's not a great article, but in it's defense it does reference [an (old) scientific article on the potential health problems associated with oxidized palm oil](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008089715153#page-1). 
If the community decides to keep this question I'll see if I can find a better reference.